# PHP: convert date time variable into date

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I'm trying to convert a date and time variable into date only in a different format:

```
$test_date = '01/07/2018 10:00-12:00';
$result = substr($test_date, 0, 10);
$newDate = date("Ymd", strtotime($result));
echo $newDate;
```

Expected result= 20180701
Actual result= 20180107

Tried all the relative variations I can find on here but keep getting 'Ydm' instead of 'Ymd'.

I'm I missing something obvious here?

Comment: `$newDate = date("Ymd", strtotime($test_date));` is all you need to do

Comment: Actually, are you using sensible date formats or American date formats

Comment: _Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed._

Comment: @RiggsFollythats still gives 'Ydm', i'm guessing American if using /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's being parsed 'wrongly' because it's not explicitly stated what the source format is, using `DateTime` objects, you can do (not tested):

```
$result = substr($test_date, 0, 10);
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $result);
$newDate = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
echo $newDate;
```

Comment: That worked, so you have to define the current format?

Comment: being explicit helps to avoid nasty surprises, otherwise you are leaving it to something internal to decide for you, I believe it tends to default to American format but might depend on the separator as mentioned by @AbraCadaver, I'd have to look it up.